# JAVA_HOME not set for wso2server.bat

Tags: java, wso2, java-home

I am trying to run wso2server.bat in windows and i have set the JAVA_HOME variable in the system variables.

Althgouh when i go into the bin folder of the wso2 folder and i run:

wso2server.bat i get the following error message:
"You must set the JAVA_HOME variable before running CARBON"

Is there any further configuration that needs to be set for carbon to recognize the JAVA_HOME variable?

Comment: try to remove the `\bin` from the JAVA_HOME

Comment: it worked! thanks a lot. @tonakai

Comment: @tonakai add that has the answer and i'll accept it pls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try to remove the `\bin` from the JAVA_HOME

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111
```

Answer (score 0):

As Tonakai answered the bin should not be part of the JAVA_HOME variable. After removal it worked fine.

Comment: Would have been nice to ask tonakai to add the answer and then you accept it. He deserves the points here, don't you think?

Comment: @Omoro i'll give him the points if he does so. I upvoted is comment because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try either of this

Windows 10 – Search for Environment Variables then select Edit the system environment variables
1 -Click the Environment Variables button.
2- Under System Variables, click New.
3In the Variable Name field, enter either:
**JAVA_HOME** if you installed the JDK (Java Development Kit)
or
**JRE_HOME** if you installed the JRE (Java Runtime Environment)
In the Variable Value field, enter your JDK or JRE installation path
in a cmd window

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2

echo %JAVA_HOME%

after these steps above try to run wso2server.bat under the installation location.
If this doesn't work then, try to adjust this bat file with the JAVA_HOME location

launcher_wso2server.bat

e.g.

> if "%JAVA_HOME%"=="" set JAVA_HOME="%~sdp0..\jdk-15.0.2\bin"